# Can't checkout project from MS-Project Server 2013

Tags: check-out, project-server, ms-project

I got a problem with MS-Project Server 2013 and MS-Project 2013 (in a Win 8.1 PC).
I can't checkout a project from the server.
It says, that a "check-in" is in progress. My SysAdmin said, that on server side everything is ok, he thinks it could be a local problem with my pc.

Cold it be, that there is a tmp-file which causes trouble, if this is possible, where can I find all tmp-files for my local MS Project 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:
Go to:
File->Project Options -> Save -->  „Clean up cache“.